# Vi: how to use bash from the vi command line?

Tags: vimrc, bash, shell

Suppose I have mapped the following function:

```
noremap <C-F12> :! bash -c "\
  git rev-parse --show-toplevel \
| xargs -I {} \
  ctags -R --sort=yes --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q {}" \
<CR>
```

No matter how I nest it, it seems as if VIM will not run the function.  I suspect a possible solution in the form of setting vim's shell to `"/usr/bin/env bash"` instead of `sh`, somehow.

But maybe there is some other solution? (or just a typo...?)

The goal here is to run the command exactly as if it were BASH and not Vim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Minimal Verifiable Solution**

`|` is a vim character, and must be escaped.

```
noremap ~~ :! 
\bash -c "git rev-parse --show-toplevel
\\| xargs -I {} 
\ctags -R --sort=yes --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q {}"<CR>
```

Note: the following will work as well

```
noremap ~~ :! 
\bash -c "git rev-parse --show-toplevel \
\| xargs -I {} 
\ctags -R --sort=yes --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q {}"<CR>
```

And this will fail:

```
noremap ~~ :! 
\bash -c "git rev-parse --show-toplevel \
\| xargs -I {} \ 
ctags -R --sort=yes --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q {}"<CR>
```

This seems to be a bug.

---

**Style Guide**

The `xargs -I {}` trick is an excellent way to maintain full control of the arguement, with lateral linux-distribution compatibility.  The purpose of `xargs` is primarily to maintain feed-forward semantics so that direction of control-flow does not hop back and forth for the downstream reader (probably yourself) unnecessarily, i.e:

```
grep 'foo' <(cat bar)
sed 's/foo/bar/' $(generate baz)
```

Further, `xargs -I {}` is semantically equivalent to `parallel --keep-order -I {}`.  `gnu-parallel` advertises compatibility with `xargs`; however, in my experience, this is superficial only; `-I {}`, however, removes the impedement.

---

**Contextual Discussion**

When writing BASH, it is preferable to use double quotes and reserve single quotes for nested languages such as `awk`, `sed`, `grep`, `perl`, etc.  This reduces clutter, and **maintains env variable substitution**. The sub-languages often have a mechanism for nested environment variable substitution through the use of flag-arguments.

An example is `awk`, which uses `-v varname=${BASH_ENV_VARIABLE}`, or `python`, which uses `-E` to turn on environment variable substitution within the single quotes.  All instructions for these sub languages, which can be used from within vim, are accessible via `info` or `man`.  `man` is available in all distributions I am aware of, and can be used as follows:

```
man <command-name>

# e.g.
man python
```

Further, `vi` can be connected to the command line vi `set -o vi`, and accessed on the fly by typing `<esc>-v`.  Context switching may be painful if you also switch to vimmish commands and system calls.

Comment: Your "Minimal Verifiable Solution" does not work for me. I get errors like `E492: Not an editor command: bash -c \\ `. I tested Vim 8.2.869 and NVIm v0.5.0-577-g48ac77a14 on Linux.

Comment: The double backslash in the above comment is a typo. Should be single.

Comment: @Ralf should work now.

Comment: @Ralf it turns out that you can put the first slash in the `\\|` escape sequence at the end of the prior line.  That should have implied that it could be used at the end of the prior line for all lines, but it did not.  That seems like a bug.  In my code, I have the remapping on one line; the original formatting was only for stack overflow.  So, tbh, it was content that I really didn't care about, but, as always, spent the most time on in stack exchange.

Comment: Nice find. This trailing backslash looks really strange.

Answer (score 3):

In Vim line continuation is done with a backslash on the new line.
Like:

```
noremap <C-F12> :!bash -c '
            \git rev-parse --show-toplevel
            \\| xargs -I {}
            \ ctags -R --sort=yes --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q {}'
            \<CR>
```

Another point is the usage of `|` in the command line, as it is a command separator for Vim (like ';' for the shell). So it has to be escaped.
See the `\\|` above? The first `\` is for line continuation, the second to escape the `|`.

See `:help line-continuation`

---

Anyway, I think your mapping could be more vimish:

```
noremap <C-F12> :call system('ctags -R --sort=yes --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q '
            \. shellescape(system('git rev-parse --show-toplevel'))) <CR>
```

This uses two  Vim functions:

- `system()` to execute a shell command and get the output
- `shellescape()` to escape a file name for usage in a shell command.

See `:help system()` and `:help shellescape()`.

Comment: Or dump the shell commands in a script and call that

Comment: regarding the comment about newlines, are you saying that when I write this remapping command in the `.vimrc` file, that the escapes do not actually espace the `\n` in the file when the file is parsed by the lisp lexer?  I say this because the literal file string would be: "`foo bar\n\whatever`", which actually back-slashes the `w` and would be un-parsable without two passes or always looking ahead to see if the next char is a slash...if that is the case, that is interesting

Comment: @Christopher "Lisp Lexer"?

Comment: Oh, no you are right, I am getting it confused with Emacs now.  Either way, VimLangauge or whatever they call it has a parser, a lexer, etc. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis here, you can read all about a waste of time.  Anyhow, processing the backslashes after the newline suggests they used some unorthodox approaches at the bottom level of whatever it is that creates the "vim-keymap and interface" (the only thing we users care about).  And all I care about is recording new keymaps in a way that is readable by me.